# curl command execute in java getting exception

Tags: java, curl

I need to execute Curl command in java but not getting any response

```
String command1 = "curl"+" "+url+" -d "+"grant_type="+grantType+" -d "+"username="+username+" -d "+"password="+password+" -d "+"client_id="+clientId+" -d "+"client_secret="+clientSecret;
//Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
```

Can someone tell me how can I execute the same in java ?

Comment: read the error stream and take a look what is happend. I guess the curl command is not found in path.

Comment: Also try printing the command1 String and see if any quoting issues exists.

Comment: String[] command = {"cmd.exe","/c", "cd \"E:\\software\\curl-7.54.0_cab\\AMD64\\CURL.EXE"+" "+url+" -d "+"grant_type="+grantType+" -d "+"username="+username+" -d "+"password="+password+" -d "+"client_id="+clientId+" -d "+"client_secret="+clientSecret};
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
    process.directory(new File("E:\\software\\curl-7.54.0_cab\\AMD64\\"));
    System.out.println("p-en--"+process.environment());
    Process p = process.start();

Comment: output am getting like below p-en--{PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6, FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO, SESSIONNAME=RDP-Tcp#0, ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64, PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\Agent\PowerShell\, SystemDrive=C:, DEFLOGDIR=C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection, DSY_DISABLE_WININET=TRUE, USERNAME=hlp_anupkha1, USERDNSDOMAIN=EMEA.ADSINT.BIZ, P
----java.lang.ProcessImpl@50040f0c

Comment: Please update the question instead of adding information in comments. Also you don't need to execute `cmd` if you need to execute `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ensure that `curl` command is in your path. If `curl` is not in your path you will have to use absolute path of `curl`.

Then I suggest you to use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) like :

```
ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("curl", "<your URL here>", "-d", "grant_type="+grantType, ...);
Process p = pb.start();
```

If you need to redirect the output of the command, you can use redirect like :

```
File log = new File("output.log");
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
```

If you need to check if the command has errors, you can use redirect like :

```
File log = new File("error.log");
pb.redirectError(Redirect.appendTo(log));
```

Comment: String[] command = {"cmd.exe","/c", "cd \"E:\\software\\curl-7.54.0_cab\\AMD64\\CURL.EXE"+" "+url+" -d "+"grant_type="+grantType+" -d "+"username="+username+" -d "+"password="+password+" -d "+"client_id="+clientId+" -d "+"client_secret="+clientSecret};
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
    process.directory(new File("C:\\Users\\sumeekha\\Downloads\\curl-7.54.0_cab\\AMD64"));
    System.out.println("p-en--"+process.environment());
    Process p = process.start();

Comment: String[] command = {"cmd.exe","/c", "cd \"E:\\software\\curl-7.54.0_cab\\AMD64\\CURL.EXE"+" "+url+" -d "+"grant_type="+grantType+" -d "+"username="+username+" -d "+"password="+password+" -d "+"client_id="+clientId+" -d "+"client_secret="+clientSecret};
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
    process.directory(new File("E:\\software\\curl-7.54.0_cab\\AMD64\\"));
    System.out.println("p-en--"+process.environment());
    Process p = process.start();----java.lang.ProcessImpl@50040f0c

Comment: Please take a closer look to what I indicate. You need to seperate each argument.